# Need explanation of fact about characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read it in wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial

On second line at beginning of page ,they have written that

$$"It\ has\ the\ determinant\ and\ the\ trace\ of\ the\ matrix\ as\ coefficients"$$

Which coefficients are  they talking about .Is this valid for complex matrices also . Can anyone throw some light on this line .Thanks

Comment: The determinant is $(-1)^n$ times the constant term and the trace is the negative of the $\lambda^{n-1}$ coefficient. This is valid for matrices over any field.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks.